# iptables: what happen after a reboot?

Tags: iptables, iptables-persistent

Installing NCPA for nagios, I found these instructions

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 5693 -j ACCEPT
apt-get install -y iptables-persistent
Answer yes to saving existing rules
```

Of course, I cannot save ALL ruleset. Because I am using failban and actually my iptables ruleset is veeeery big.

I'd like to persist only

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 5693 -j ACCEPT
```

Is it possible?

Is still really needed to use iptables-persistent to keep firewall rules? I have a doubt because I am using port 80 and a few others without any problems after system reboots...

So, When I reboot the system, will normally iptables reset all rules? 
If yes Why ? If no .. wel...

Comment: Why is it a problem to have a lot of rules. What problem do you see when you try to persist so many?

Comment: Your question is right. Having fail2ban on a production and old server we have actually more than 12.000 banned ips. I prefer to recreate the ban list next reboot. But of course is not a technical problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption about this behaviour is correct. Upon reboot, if rules are not made persistent, they are lost.

Here is discussed in details how to make rules persist: https://serverfault.com/questions/626521/centos-7-save-iptables-settings

Comment: Thanks. What if I install ufw? I noticed on a different vps that with ufw installed the rules ( of ufw not all the single lines ) were not lost